# Pixel Color in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, colors, es6-promise, pixel

Let me preface this by saying I am completely new to JavaScript, React, React Native, etc...

I am trying to use the React Native module [react-native-pixel-color][1] to get the color of a specified pixel but have been stuck trying to figure it out for some time now. The module states:

"promise getHex(path, options) 
The promise resolves with a string containing the uri of the new file."

But I am unsure how to go about this? I call the function getPixelColor and pass it an image_uri but I keep getting the following error in the console:

Error: "Cannot read property 'getHex' of undefined" in TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHex' of undefined << at eval (module://react-native-pixel-color.js:3:1252) << at new Promise () << at Object.o [as getHex] (module://react-native-pixel-color.js:3:1197) ...

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => getPixelColor('https://i.imgur.com/TkIrScD.png')}>
        <Text>Pick a photo</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

function getPixelColor(image_uri) {
  var x = 10;
  var y = 10;

  const getHex = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(image_uri);
    if (image_uri) {
      console.log('Resolved');
      resolve('Stuff worked!');
    } else {
      console.log('Rejected');
      reject(Error('It broke'));
    }
  });

  PixelColor.getHex(image_uri, { x, y })

    .then(color => {
      // #000000
      console.log(color);
    })

    .catch(err => {
      // Oops, something went wrong. Check that the filename is correct and
      // inspect err to get more details.
      console.log('Something Went Wrong');
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the whole page (including the imports)?

Comment: did you find anything for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have something that does that out of the box. You can also look at the code to see how they do it:

https://github.com/bvic23/react-native-get-pixel